# MNIST Tensor CNTK Python Project Fails to Load in Visual Studio

Tags: python, visual-studio

I attempted to download and build a Visual Studio solution from the Github project found here: https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/MNISTTensorCNTK

I am unfamiliar with using Python in Visual Studio.  The Python project within this solution says "Load Failed", and when I try to reload the project, a popup says there is a missing project subtype[image]

[image: Pictures of Error Message and Solution Explorer]

Googling the missing subtype was unsuccessful.

I've tried 2 separate computer, and I've tried repair installation, and adding/modifying Python to Visual Studio.

Please advise on possible solutions.

Comment: I have the same problem. :(

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and it's solved after following the instructions here:
https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/MNISTTensorCNTK/issues/2

**Summary:**
Changed ProjectTypeGuids inside the project file to this --
{a41c8ea1-112a-4a2d-9f91-29557995525f};{888888a0-9f3d-457c-b088-3a5042f75d52}

**Important:** re-loading the project after this change is not enough, you must save the change, close and re-open Visual Studio.